# Invalid keystore format

Tags: android, keystore, keytool, apk, code-signing-certificate

I was given a keystore file along with an username and password and I need to sign the updated application. However, I am getting "keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format" when trying to list the contents of the file, trying to create a new key in the keystore, etc.

I have looked at the similar posts, but none of them helped me.

I am looking forward to hearing a solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the file was an RAR archive file that contained the actual keystore.